# Resizing a Chart.js chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The Chart Spans across the entire Web Page and I cant resize it. I've tried seting the height/width of the canvas and the canvas with no luck.
Here is my Html:

```
<div id="chartbox">
<canvas id="myChart" display="block"></canvas>
</div>


<script>
var xaxis = [1,2,3,4,5]
var yaxis = [2,3,4,5,6]


var thisChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    responsive: true
},
  data: {
    labels: xaxis,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: yaxis,
        label: "Test",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",

      }
    ]
  }
});


</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are styling the canvas element directly with non relative values you need to set `responsive` to false in the options, if you are styling the width with relative values you need to apply them to the surrounding div

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/responsive.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer is helpful to you, you just have to specify certain CSS rules for the parent element of the graphic.

```js
var xaxis = [1,2,3,4,5]
var yaxis = [2,3,4,5,6]


var thisChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    responsive: true
},
  data: {
    labels: xaxis,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: yaxis,
        label: "Test",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",

      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
#chartbox {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chartbox">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```